# Django Rest API: View definition delete queryset

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I'm still pretty new to creating views in Django Rest Framework, I can make basic views but I still have no clue about definitions so please help me out here.

I've got this View which gets the answers of a question (by a given question id). The list definition works perfectly, however I want to make a delete_all function which deletes these results. You can see what I came up with below.

URL

```
router.register('manager/course/question/answers', QuestionAnswerView)


http://.../manager/course/question/answers/5 works.
http://.../manager/course/question/answers/delete_all/5 does not work.
```

View

```
class QuestionAnswerView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QuestionAnswer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionAnswerSerializer

    # works
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = QuestionAnswer.objects.all()
        if request.query_params:
            question_id = request.query_params['question_id']
            queryset = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_id)
        serializer = QuestionAnswerSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    # does not work
    def delete_all(self, request):
        if request.query_params:
            question_id = request.query_params['question_id']
            queryset = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_id)
            queryset.delete()
        return Response('success')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all explained in [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset):

> The ModelViewSet class inherits from GenericAPIView and includes implementations for various actions, by mixing in the behavior of the various mixin classes.
> The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are `.list(), .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy()`.

So there is no `delete_all()`. You will have to tell the viewset and the router to [make it available](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing):

> If you have ad-hoc methods that should be routable, you can mark them as such with the @action decorator.